# OpenCV+PYTHON: HOGDescriptor readALTModel(filename)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, detection, svmlight

does anybody know if there is a way to use the function readALTModel(filename) in the (cpp) HOGDescriptor class with python/opencv?

Thanks!